# Issues with String Array Concatenation

Tags: java, arrays, string, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate all strings in an array. I want for example `["a","b","c"]` to become `"abc"`. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Laggaihop 
{
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Ange antal ord: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        int antal = Integer.parseInt(input);
        String[] ordlista;
        ordlista = new String[antal];
        for(int i = 0; i < antal; i++){
            System.out.print("Ange ord: ");
            String nyttelement = scanner.nextLine();
            ordlista[i] = nyttelement;
        }
        String resultat;
        for(int i = 0; i < antal; i++){
            resultat = resultat+ordlista[i];
        }


    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Laggaihop.java:21: error: variable resultat might not have been initialized
            resultat = resultat+ordlista[i];
```

Why is this? I **have** initialized the variable in the row `String resultat;`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you have **declared** the variable. **Initializing** means you have given it an **initial value**. You can do this by replacing the line with:

```
String resultat = "";
```

Or you can do it in two separate steps:

```
String resultat; //declaration
resultat = "";   //initializiation
```

As far as I know, Java only **initializes fields automatically**. For local variables, it does less automation. Probably because this is assumed to be error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

All local variables need to be initalised before being used. Doing so will solve the compilation error. In your program you have declared the variable `resultat` but have not initialised it.

**Section 4.12.5 in Java 8 Language Specification states:**

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

Comment: Based on the question, I think the OP is confusing initializing with declaring...

Answer (score 1):

```
String resultat;
resultat=resultat+something;
                   ^what is value in here?
```

Or

```
String resultat; //declared
resultat="something";//initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the String resultat. The final code would look like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Laggaihop
{
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Ange antal ord: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        int antal = Integer.parseInt(input);
        String[] ordlista;
        ordlista = new String[antal];
        for(int i = 0; i < antal; i++){
            System.out.print("Ange ord: ");
            String nyttelement = scanner.nextLine();
            ordlista[i] = nyttelement;
        }
        String resultat="";
        for(int i = 0; i < antal; i++){
            resultat = resultat+ordlista[i];
        }
        System.out.println(resultat);
    }
}
```

This should solve your issue.